# removing SpiderOak

Tags: software-installation

SpiderOak removing FAQ says that i need to delete the ~/.SpiderOak folder. I have uninstalled the application but I don't want to go deleting things and mess something up. Can someone please give a set by step guide on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you delete the `~/.SpiderOak` folder mentioned in [SpiderOak's website](http://spideroak.com/faq/questions/38/how_do_i_completely_remove_spideroak_from_a_device/), you will merely remove a particular user from SpiderOak but you won't affect its performance. Please notice that, as for **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** and **SpiderOak 5.1.3**, the old `~/.SpiderOak` folder  is now located at `~/.config/SpiderOak`

As for the procedure, you need to open **Terminal** (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute this command:

```
rm -r ~/.SpiderOak
```

That will delete the `~/.SpiderOak` folder and all its contents. Conversely, if you are using a more recent version, you need to delete the `~/.config/SpiderOak` folder instead:

```
rm -r ~/.config/SpiderOak
```